# Packages from pip conflicting with pacman

Tags: pacman, manjaro

I'm trying to install `openshot` on Manjaro linux.

I end up getting a long error with several files each followed by `exists in file-system`. I recognise some of these packages as ones I've installed using `pip` for some of my personal projects.

Is this a case of both `pip` and `pacman` trying to manage the same files and failing?

How can I solve the conflict?

Error:

```
Total Installed Size:  219.89 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n] 
(18/18) checking keys in keyring                                                           [#####################################################] 100%
(18/18) checking package integrity                                                         [#####################################################] 100%
(18/18) loading package files                                                              [#####################################################] 100%
(18/18) checking for file conflicts                                                        [#####################################################] 100%
error: failed to commit transaction (conflicting files)
python-olefile: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/OleFileIO_PL.py exists in filesystem
python-olefile: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/olefile/CONTRIBUTORS.txt exists in filesystem
python-olefile: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/olefile/LICENSE.txt exists in filesystem
python-olefile: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/olefile/README.html exists in filesystem
python-olefile: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/olefile/README.rst exists in filesystem
python-olefile: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/olefile/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python-olefile: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/olefile/olefile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/BdfFontFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/BmpImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/BufrStubImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ContainerIO.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/CurImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/DcxImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/DdsImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/EpsImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ExifTags.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/FitsStubImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/FliImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/FontFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/FpxImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/FtexImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/GbrImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/GdImageFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/GifImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/GimpGradientFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/GimpPaletteFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/GribStubImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/IcnsImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/IcoImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageChops.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageColor.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageDraw2.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageEnhance.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFilter.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageGrab.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageMath.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageMode.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageMorph.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageOps.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImagePalette.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImagePath.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageQt.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageSequence.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageShow.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageStat.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageTransform.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageWin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImtImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/IptcImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/JpegPresets.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/McIdasImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/MicImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/MpegImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/MpoImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/MspImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/OleFileIO.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PSDraw.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PaletteFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PalmImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PcdImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PcfFontFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PcxImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PdfImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PixarImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PngImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PpmImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PsdImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/PyAccess.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/SgiImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/SpiderImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/SunImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TarIO.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/TiffTags.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/WalImageFile.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/WebPImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/WmfImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/XVThumbImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/XbmImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/XpmImagePlugin.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__init__.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/BdfFontFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/BmpImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/BufrStubImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ContainerIO.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/CurImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/DcxImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/DdsImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/EpsImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ExifTags.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/FitsStubImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/FliImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/FontFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/FpxImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/FtexImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/GbrImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/GdImageFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/GifImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/GimpGradientFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/GimpPaletteFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/GribStubImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/Hdf5StubImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/IcnsImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/IcoImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/Image.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageChops.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageCms.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageColor.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageDraw.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageDraw2.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageEnhance.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageFilter.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageFont.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageGrab.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageMath.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageMode.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageMorph.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageOps.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImagePalette.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImagePath.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageQt.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageSequence.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageShow.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageStat.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageTk.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageTransform.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImageWin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/ImtImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/IptcImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/Jpeg2KImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/JpegImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/JpegPresets.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/McIdasImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/MicImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/MpegImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/MpoImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/MspImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/OleFileIO.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PSDraw.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PaletteFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PalmImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PcdImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PcfFontFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PcxImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PdfImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PixarImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PngImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PpmImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PsdImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/PyAccess.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/SgiImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/SpiderImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/SunImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/TarIO.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/TgaImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/TiffImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/TiffTags.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/WalImageFile.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/WebPImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/WmfImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/XVThumbImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/XbmImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/XpmImagePlugin.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/__init__.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/_binary.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/_tkinter_finder.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/_util.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/__pycache__/features.cpython-36.pyc exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_binary.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imagingcms.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imagingft.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imagingmath.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imagingmorph.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imagingtk.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_tkinter_finder.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_util.py exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_webp.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so exists in filesystem
python-pillow: /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/features.py exists in filesystem
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Comment: Yes, basically `pacman` wants to install these packages for you and is sure they are not installed. Then it makes a sanity check and surprisingly finds corresponding files in your system which means it can't get it right. So `pacman` aborts the installation. I think deleting them with `pip` and letting `pacman` install them for you would do the trick.

Comment: @ddnomad that seemed to work for a quick fix. This might get confusing in the future as some packages might not be directly installed. Especially when installing from requirments.txt

Comment: consider using `virtualenv` to omit such issues.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
sudo pacman -S <package> --overwrite '*'
```

Or maybe (not sure whether `overwrite` will work for update)

```
sudo pacman -Syu --overwrite '*'
```

Answer (score 0):

delete those directories and file also OleFileIO_PL.py, olefile/, PIL/
then install whatever you want using pacman.